# How to select the first column to add a ascending number in each?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have been trying to generate a table via Javascript. It should resemble an Excel table but only to a max of 100. Furthermore in each cell there are buttons which have a spefic use for something else.
This is one the tasks for my internship.

So far I have managed it on the XAxis but I have no clue how to add it on the YAxis.

An Example how it should look like:

[image: Example]

```js
var abc = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
  'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW', 'AX', 'AY', 'AZ'
];

var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("Table");
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
table.border = '1';
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);

for (var i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('TR');
  tableBody.appendChild(tr);


  for (var j = 0; j < 52; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('TD');
    td.width = '75';

    if (i == 0) {
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(abc[j]));

    } else {
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.innerHTML = "";
      td.appendChild(button);
    }

    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
}



myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="Table"></div>
```

Comment: Can you add the full javascript code and html one too?

Comment: I made you a snippet. I had to remove to code. Please update the snippet with relevant code and CSS

Comment: I as a hint, I prefer using `table.insertRow` and `row.insertCell` rather than creating them from tag name and then adding them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean this?

```
var td = document.createElement("td")
td.innerHTML=(i>0)?i:"&nbsp;"
tr.appendChild(td)
```

```js
var abc = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
  'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW', 'AX', 'AY', 'AZ'
];

var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("Table");
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
table.border = '1';
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);

for (var i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('TR');
  tableBody.appendChild(tr);
  var td = document.createElement("td")
  td.innerHTML=(i>0)?i:"&nbsp;"
  tr.appendChild(td)

  for (var j = 0; j < 52; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('TD');
    td.width = '75';

    if (i == 0) {
      td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(abc[j]));

    } else {
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.innerHTML = "";
      td.appendChild(button);
    }

    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
}



myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
```

```css
td:nth-child(1) { text-align:right }
button { height:15px; width:26px }
```

```html
<div id="Table"></div>
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an working demo

```js
var abc = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
  'AA', 'AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'AE', 'AF', 'AG', 'AH', 'AI', 'AJ', 'AK', 'AL', 'AM', 'AN', 'AO', 'AP', 'AQ', 'AR', 'AS', 'AT', 'AU', 'AV', 'AW', 'AX', 'AY', 'AZ'
];

var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("Table");
var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
table.border = '1';
var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY');
table.appendChild(tableBody);

for (var i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
  var tr = document.createElement('TR');
  tableBody.appendChild(tr);

  for (var j = 0; j < 52; j++) {
    var td = document.createElement('TD');
    td.width = '75';

    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
      td.innerHTML = '';

    } else if (i == 0 && j != 0) {
      td.innerHTML = abc[j - 1];

    } else if (j == 0 && i != 0) {
      td.innerHTML = i;
      
    } else {
      var button = document.createElement("button");
      button.innerHTML = "";
      td.appendChild(button);
    }

    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
}

myTableDiv.appendChild(table);
```

```html
<div id="Table"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you,for that fast answer!